# asp.net mvc: making a table/class with ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a Post table, where User can write a Title and Message and post it. Thing is, my user is from the ApplicationUser : IdentityUser class. I'm not 100 % sure how to put the User in my table.

So I have this model class:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string message { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

}
```

And a DbContext:

```
   public class PostDbContext : DbContext
{
    public PostDbContext()
        : base("PostDbContext")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a controller, it gives me this error:

**TimmWeb.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined.**

The same line is repeated for IdentityUserRole. I don't understand why I get this error?

Also, in my IdentityModels.cs, I've made an Modelbuilder to change AspNetUsers to Users:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Change the name of the table to be Users instead of AspNetUsers
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
    }
}
```

Where do I go wrong? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think you want IdentityUser mapped to table. AppUser inherits from it? Then that's all you need to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit. Your custom classes `IdentityUserLogin` and `IdentityUserRole` have no key defined or, more explicitly, have no property named `Id`, or named something else that would match by convention, or that is decorated with `[Key]`.

I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here, but the Identity versions of these classes are what's bound by default to the subclass of `IdentityUser`, i.e. `ApplicationUser`. If you want to alter them in some way, then you should be subclassing them and then you need specify your versions in all the generic type arguments.

Also, if you want to relate entities from your application with the user from Identity, then they both need to use the *same* context. In other words, your `ApplicationDbContext` needs to house your `Post` entity and `PostDbContext` needs to go away.

Comment: Okey, using the same DbContext clearly were very important, and that helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to attach a user to a post entity you should

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string message { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema:false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Change the name of the table to be Users instead of AspNetUsers
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasRequired(p => p.User)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```